# Made Consecutive Transactions But Unconfirmed at Blockchain.info wallet

Tags: transactions, blockchain, blockchain.info, unconfirmed-transactions, lost-bitcoins

I received a sum of bitcoins and when i start spending it they are now unconfirmed.

When the first happened, i made another transaction immediately.
When the second shows that the problem still persist i made a third
Why is this happening. I paid the fees automatically generated by the blockchain.info system.

Is this due to my fee's are too? 
will it still be unconfirmed if i made a forth transaction?

Was hoping to make a forth transaction of a dollar with a dollar fee. By percentage, and amount, those miners will be dying for my fee right?

why i wanna do this bcos according to my understanding, if they confirm my forth transaction, they would have to confirm the first 3 as well as the balance have to tally anyways for it to be legit and valid.

PLease advice and correct me if i am wrong
its been many hours and im tired of waiting
worried that the btc is gone or something

p.s i kinda spend the received btc before 1st confirmation, does it matter?
any solutions, advice, remedies etc will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, guys, guess the greed of mankind prevails and supercedes all trials and tribulations.

i, initiated a forth transaction, with a fee of approx $0.74.
next i know, within an hour, im out of the waiting list and all other transactions i made earlier followed through.

hope this helps. 
all the best
its a cold heartless money talking world out there.

Answer (score 0):

[According to blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/address/17wWzcAXjKjG3LQcGCYJbu7cdi6LgaXB4t), the receipt of bitcoins to 17wWzcAXjKjG3LQcGCYJbu7cdi6LgaXB4t has been confirmed (43 times so far).

However, [the proceeding transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/77d1f8f706747f1f10e1de8a02083f91cdca178a47cdfe6b2f53e7b9a4921592) that removes the bitcoins from 17wWzcAXjKjG3LQcGCYJbu7cdi6LgaXB4t has not yet been confirmed.

This is likely being caused by the [current transaction backlog of about 62,000 unconfirmed transactions.](https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions) Blockchain.info does regard your transaction as a "High Priority" transaction, so hopefully it will confirm soon, but keep in mind that the backlog is considerably large right now.

Your bitcoins are safe, but they may be in limbo for several hours. The transaction will eventually either be confirmed or be dropped from the network. If confirmed, the coins will go to the intended recipient addresses. If dropped, the coins will remain in 17wWzcAXjKjG3LQcGCYJbu7cdi6LgaXB4t.

Comment: what about the 4th transaction idea. u think it will work? it just annoys me to see it unconfirmed.

Comment: base on the table from https://bitcoinfees.21.co/
i noticed that the fees recommended by blockchain.info is abit low.
i calculated that i shld pay 0.15usd. not sure if i calculated it wrongly or not. could this be why too?

Comment: It may. That concept is generally referred to as child-pays-for-parent and some miners may operate using it.

Comment: I mean, if you control the recipient address for the unconfirmed transaction, you could make a new transaction from the recipient address with a much higher fee (hence child-pays-for-parent). But if you do not control the recipient address, it's a waiting game then.

Comment: ok. ima try and hopefully a $1 transaction with a $1 fee is enticing enough. will update once i have any form of confirmation or result.

Comment: oh, it works. WAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA 37mins to the first confirmation. star this post, spread the news.